# How to set command to populate django data through txt file DJANGO

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

thanks for your time:

I got a model that has to be filled with 3 txt documents that got 40 rows each. the command should open each take the line, set the objects, save it, and be called again in a range 40:

I'm beeing able to call it 40 times although i the 40 ones are tanking the same last line how can i set a count on the txt file to go to the next line when be called again? should i set a split to get the lines as a list? and set the line like a list index `list[counter]`?

models.py:

```
class MP4 (models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True, max_length=300)
    imagem = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='')
    artista = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, default='Unknown')
```

seeder.py (command):

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    file_name = ['nome.txt', 'artista.txt', 'url.txt']


    @classmethod
    def handle(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        counter = 0
        for row in range(40):
            counter += 1 
            with open(cls.file_name[0]) as file:
                for linha in file:
                    nome = linha

            with open(cls.file_name[1]) as file:
                for linha in file:
                    artista = linha

            with open(cls.file_name[2]) as file:
                for linha in file:
                    url = linha

            row = MP4(
                nome=nome,
                url=url,
                artista=artista,
                id=MP4.objects.latest('id').id + 1
                )

            row.save()
```

nome.txt:

```
Somewhere over the Rainbow
ocean drive
Michael Jackson - Billie Jean ( cover by J.Fla )
...
```

url.txt:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1bFr2SWP1I&list=RDV1bFr2SWP1I&start_radio=1
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDxJlW6cxRk&list=RDVHoT4N43jK8&index=19
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J1AdPY73qxo
...
```

artista.txt

```
gordinho havaiano
duke dumont
Michael Jackson
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could open all the 3 files together, and loop it with a zip.

```py
file_name = ['nome.txt', 'artista.txt', 'url.txt']
with open(file_name[0]) as file1, open(file_name[1]) as file2, open(file_name[2]) as file3:
    for data in zip(file1, file2, file3):
        nome, artista, url = data
         row = MP4(
            nome=nome,
            url=url,
            artista=artista,
            id=MP4.objects.latest('id').id + 1
            )
        row.save()
```

Comment: although i ain't got much idea about the zip part any tip tutorial to study?